# Using setTimeOut on user input to trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```js
$("#test").on("keyup", (e) => {
  if(e.target.value.length === 3) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("fired")
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

If the user enters 3 characters, `console.log("fired")` gets automatically fired after 2 seconds (That works with the above code)

But if the user types another character during this time, I need to be able to clear the old time out and wait for 2 seconds again.

Once this times out, it should just run as expected. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

```
let timeOut;

$("#test").on("keyup", (e) => {
  if(e.target.value.length === 3) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("fired if length is 3")
    }, 2000)
  } else if (e.target.value.length === 4) {
    clearTimeout(timeOut)
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("fired if length is 4")
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

Comment: Do you want to fire the event if chars count is in multiple of 3 like 3,6,9,12 ?

Comment: Set the timeout as a global variable, i.e. `var timeout`. Then use `clearTimeout(timeout)` to remove the existing timer, and `timeout = setTimeout(...)` to restart it.

Comment: @Abhishek I think the OP wants to fire the event if the length is >= 3

Comment: Then he need to change the condition and use `clearTimeout` as described by you and @TylerRoper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store a reference to the timeout and you can then reset it using the reference and the function clearTimeout when the creation of the timeout is triggered again.

You can also store a flag to track whether the message has been fired and use this flag to abort further actions.

```js
let timeOut,
    hasFired = false;

$("#test").on("keyup", (e) => {
  if ( hasFired ) {
    return;
  }
  if(e.target.value.length >= 3) {
    clearTimeout( timeOut );
    let message = "length is " + e.target.value.length;
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log( message );
      hasFired = true;
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

Comment: What happens in `clearTimeout( timer )` the first time the condition is met?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Not my answer, but the answer is *nothing*, which should work perfectly in your case.

Comment: I've edited the main post with another approach. Please tell me if I'm wrong/right.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You shouldn't really be editing the question based on answers that you received to your initial question. In any event, unless you want something different to happen for 3 characters vs 4 characters (to warrant the `if` statement), I see no reason why you'd use that code instead of  the code in JasonB's answer.

Comment: Btw, this code keeps firing every time you add a new character. `console.log` should ONLY fire if user enters a new value in the time we are waiting for the first `console.log` to fire.

Comment: Not quite @ZeroDarkThirty. What if I type 4 chars, delete 2 and add 1? Then you'll see both alerts. You also have some duplicated code in there which is bad form maintenace down the road.

Comment: Gotcha. But please refer to my last comment. This code isn't doing what its supposed to.

Comment: Edited my answer, but your initial question didn't include this request. If there are further requirements, you should probably start a new question. Notice how I set the message text and then set the timeout, if you organize your code this way, you can more easily track what's happening and there won't be multiple set timeout requests. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. But my question did mention this.. "But if the user types another character *during this time*"

Comment: Right on. Good luck with the project.